# How to run the "PushNotification" Sample on the MF Test Server (Remote Server)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I try to run the sample push notification, from getting started (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/), on the MF Server using WAS and DB2. The sample inside the MF Studio Eclipse works on the MF development server.

**Problem:** Getting a pushNotification on the MobilDevice

- IT WORKS with MF Studio Eclipse on the default the MF development server
- IT DOES NOT WORK on the MF TEST SERVER using WAS and DB2

Question: How to run the "PushNotification" Sample on the MF Test Server?

**Following environment is given:**

MF Server (WAS,DB2)

```
  MobileFirstTestServer (ServerConfiguration)
       |-> PushNotifications (Environment)
          |-> PushNotification (Application) (Deployed)
          |-> PushAdapter (Adapter) (Deployed)
          |-> Device Registered
```

**Using the browser to submit a notification works:**

*Request:*

```
    http://192.168.126.133:9082/PushNotifications/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=[%22Thomas%22,%22TEST%22]
```

*Response from the adapter:*

```
   /*-secure-
    {"isSuccessful":true,"result":"Notification :: TEST is sent to user :: Thomas"}*/
```

**Adapter Code:**

```
 WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);
 WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
return { result: "Notification :: " + notificationText + " is sent to user :: " + userId };
```

It seems "WL.Server.notifyAllDevices" does not work, but why?

Any idea?

**LogCat Device**

```
   04-22 11:12:18.280: D/WLNativeXHR(3146): callback {"headers":{"Content-Language":"en-US","Date":"Wed, 22 Apr 2015 16:22:18 GMT","Content-Length":"70","P3P":"policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"","Expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Pragma":"no-cache","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},"status":200,"responseText":"/*-secure-\n{\"isSuccessful\":true,\"warnings\":[],\"errors\":[],\"info\":[]}*/\n","statusText":"OK"}
   04-22 11:12:18.280: W/PluginManager(3146): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to LoggerPlugin.log blocked the main thread for 46ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
   04-22 11:12:18.296: D/NONE(3146): Application is now  online.
   04-22 11:12:18.324: D/NONE(3146): response [/apps/services/api/PushNotifications/android/notifications] success: /*-secure-
   04-22 11:12:18.324: D/NONE(3146): {"isSuccessful":true,"warnings":[],"errors":[],"info":[]}*/
   04-22 11:12:18.344: D/CordovaLog(3146): file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js: Line 5755 : No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration
   04-22 11:12:18.344: I/Web Console(3146): No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration at file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:5755
   04-22 11:12:18.448: D/dalvikvm(3146): GC_CONCURRENT freed 244K, 14% free 9237K/10631K, paused 37ms+8ms, total 63ms
   04-22 11:12:22.440: D/NONE(3146): Piggybacking event transmission
   04-22 11:12:22.440: D/NONE(3146): Flush called
```

**WAS TRACE LOG** .. working push .. *after changing the Firewall settings and the log level of was for the MF Test Server (Remote Server)*

```
  [4/24/15 10:19:53:754 CEST] 00000160  E UOW= source=com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet class=com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet method=createAjaxRequestExceptionJSON org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 4] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAALb] appName=[IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer]
      FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: Notification token unknown, subscribe to PushAdapter.PushEventSource failed. [project PushNotifications]
   [4/24/15 10:19:53:767 CEST] 00000160  E UOW= source=com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet method=createAjaxRequestExceptionJSON org=null prod=null component=null thread=[WebContainer : 4] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAALb] appName=[IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer]
      FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project PushNotifications]Notification token unknown, subscribe to PushAdapter.PushEventSource failed., User Identity {wl_anonymousUserRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:0ef47860-0edb-3d98-b495-df2c2efd3cbc, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), wl_directUpdateRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:92h5o8g0b3n396s0ovnbjhhr1k, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLRemoteDisableNullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null, PushAppRealm=(name:Thomas, loginModule:PushAppLoginModule), SubscribeServlet=null, myserver=(name:Thomas, loginModule:PushAppLoginModule)}. [project PushNotifications]
  [4/24/15 10:20:34:639 CEST] 00000160  E UOW= source=com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation class=com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation method=sendMessage org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 4] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAALr] appName=[IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer]
      FWLSE0227E: Failed to send notification. Reason: FPWSE0009E: Internal server error. No devices found [project PushNotifications]
 [4/24/15 10:21:43:126 CEST] 00000161  E UOW= source=com.ibm.isclite.runtime.aggregation.tags.PageTitleTag class=com.ibm.isclite.runtime.aggregation.tags.PageTitleTag method= doStartTag() org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAAMI] appName=[isclite]
      CWLAA5015W: Exception while rendering a page: com.ibm.isclite.datastore.TitleServiceException: Error retrieving title for "com.ibm.isclite.wccm.base.impl.TextImpl@ecc458d2 (string: null, uniqueName: null)" 
 [4/24/15 10:21:43:130 CEST] 00000161  W UOW= source=com.ibm.isclite.runtime.aggregation.tags.WindowTitleTag class=com.ibm.isclite.runtime.aggregation.tags.WindowTitleTag method=doStartTag() org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAAMI] appName=[isclite]
      CWLAA5015W: Exception while rendering a page: com.ibm.isclite.datastore.TitleServiceException: Error retrieving title for "com.ibm.isclite.wccm.base.impl.TextImpl@a895a4ef (string: null, uniqueName: null)" 
 [4/24/15 10:22:16:666 CEST] 00000161  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper method=init org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAAMZ] appName=[IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer]
      SRVE0242I: [IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer] [/PushNotifications] [ClientLogUploaderServlet]: Initialization successful.
  [4/24/15 10:22:17:297 CEST] 00000161  W UOW= source=com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator class=com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator method=addTokenToAndroidKey org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAAMb] appName=[IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_PushNotificationsMobileFirstTestServer]
      FPWSE1079W: GCM push token APA91bHtOJXjXtQvq_goqKOFvqM5ZRT8zwJEmD6U5Jyqi7hxh-EYDyv9lx0JS4LfhyPNdekJs2oYAnYpmmlqx19k9fwoE69CvZaox61u-WO6xuNE_dskvLw2lqspHoqYr9ZMwH6-gY00APw7IPXMIowDTBafzHyFVQ is not added to GCM notification key. GCM Service invocation failed (reason: notification_key already exists)
      com.ibm.pushworks.server.exceptions.GCMException: GCM Service invocation failed (reason: notification_key already exists)
at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendToGCM(GCMSender.java:409)
at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMSender.java:353)
at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.addTokenToAndroidKey(GCMMediator.java:206)
at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.getNotificationKey(PushServiceImpl.java:1215)
at com.ibm.pushworks.server.core.PushServiceImpl.registerDevice(PushServiceImpl.java:429)
at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.updateDeviceToken(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:403)
at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.NotificationSubscriptionHandler.doPost(NotificationSubscriptionHandler.java:126)
at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

  [4/24/15 10:24:35:150 CEST] 00000161  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper method=init org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAANT] appName=[isclite]
      SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.probdetermination/customSelectDropLayout.jsp]: Initialization successful.
 [4/24/15 10:24:40:938 CEST] 00000161  I UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper method=init org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 5] requestID=[AAAGStFDCFY-AAAAAAAAANV] appName=[isclite]
      SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.probdetermination/logfileViewLayout.jsp]: Initialization successful.
```

Comment: Where is the error in your question? Do you not get the notification in the device? Mention the problem, add client logs, server logs...

Comment: The error is: On the Mobile Device I do not get the notification.

Comment: Verify in your test server's network that all required addresses and ports are open for outgoing and incoming connections: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/#projectSetupAndGuidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LogCat log is incomplete. It does not show that the device was able to receive a notification token, subscribe for push notifications on the MFP server, etc...

1. Provide a fuller LogCat log
2. Verify in your test server's network that all required addresses and ports are open for outgoing and incoming connections that are listed for Android, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/#projectSetupAndGuidelines

Comment: After I changed some firewall dettings and the log-level of the WAS for the MF Test Server( Remote Server) it works. 

-> Just for Documentation: I inserted the success WAS-log into my question.

Thanks for paying attention to my question.

Comment: Hello Idan, 

I created a sample video for the deployment of the "push notification sample" to the test remote server.

https://youtu.be/ea5hdKgF4AQ

Maybe this is useful in the future for some situations.

Regards, Thomas